# Countability and Surjectivity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f : A\rightarrow B$ is surjective with $A$ being countable. Show that the set $A' = \{a_i \in A : f(a_i) \neq f(a_j) \mbox{ for all $j= 1,2,3\ldots, i-1$} \}$ is non -empty.

I am unsure as to whether include $a_1$ or not, if I enumerate the elements of A as ($a_1,a_2,a_3....)$

Comment: Isn't $a_1$ always trivially in $A'$?

Comment: If you're excluding $a_1$ from $A'$, then I don't even think it is true. Let $B$ be a singleton and $f$ be constant.

Comment: @kccu I'm not sure whether to exclude $a_1$ or not.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto 0 : \Bbb{N} \to \{0\}$ seems to be a counter-example to the claim.

Comment: What is $B$? Is there any restriction?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin nope

Comment: Then you have a choice: either you allow $i=1$, in which case the condition is empty so $a_1\in A’$, or you do not allow $i=1$, in which case the statement is wrong. Of course, as written the statement doesn’t make much sense until you fix a surjection $\mathbb{N}\to A$, since otherwise, “$a_i$” doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin what do you mean by "in which case the condition is empty .."?

Comment: If $i=1$, then there is no $j$ with $1\leq j\leq i-1$. So you have a condition that must be satisfied by all elements in the empty set, which means that it is vacuously true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"for all $j=1,2,3,...,i-1$" is an informal and  sloppy style, of the "you-know-what-I-mean" variety, and sometimes you don't know unless you're telepathic.

What is meant is "for all $j\in \Bbb N$ such that $j<i$".